# Swiper with relative units for breakpoints property

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, swiper.js

I want to use swiper 'responsive breakpoints' demo. Since I want everything on my page to be defined in relative units (such as REM or EM), I have problem with changing pixels into rem in this plugin - (https://codesandbox.io/s/cgmkkh).

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.logo-slider', {
    ...
    breakpoints: {
        0: {
          slidesPerView: 2
        },
        450: {
          slidesPerView: 3
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 4
        },
        1000: {
          slidesPerView: 5
        },
    }
});
```

Is it posible to use REM instead of pixels in swiper plugin? It is totally different if user use 16px (default) or e.g. 24px font-size in the browser.

I tried with getting font-size of the 'html' and multiple it with certain value (e.g. for 450px => 450px / 16px (defualt) = 28,125rem). However, if user again change browser font-size, it can work only when page is reloaded.

```
var el = document.querySelector('html');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
var fontSize = parseFloat(style); 
console.log(fontSize);

var breakpoint450 = 28.125 * fontSize;
console.log(aa);

var swiper = new Swiper('.logo-slider', {
    loop: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    spaceBetween: 20,

    breakpoints: {
        0: {
          slidesPerView: 2
        },
        [breakpoint450]: {
          slidesPerView: 3
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 4
        },
        1000: {
          slidesPerView: 5
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: `em` or `rem` aren't usable in swiper js, maybe you could rely on "ratio breakpoints"? see this: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-ratio-breakpoints-vrs48z

Comment: actually no, because it's ratio between width and height. I want for the same viewport dimensions but different font size. If you want big font-size, for 450px three columns will be very narrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.onfocus` to calculate desirable breakpoints and reinit your `Swiper` instance. If possible, please avoid preserving its current slide or something about `Swiper` instance's current state, just let it reinitialize from the very beginning.